# 405: Method Not Allowed in WebClient.FileUpload method

Tags: c#, iis, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file in `Voices` Directory to IIS website using the following code-

```
System.Net.WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
string sourceFilePath = e.FullPath;
string webAddress = "http://111.222.333.444:1012/Voices/";
string destinationFilePath = webAddress + e.Name;
webClient.UploadFile(destinationFilePath, "PUT", sourceFilePath);
webClient.Dispose();
```

It gives me an exception `405: Method Not Allowed`. This code runs on WinForm application.

Is there any config issue on server side?

Comment: Well what *have* you done to enable a file upload in IIS? Is this just a vanilla IIS site, or is it running a .NET webapp?

Comment: @Json Skeet, it's a .NET webapp.

Comment: Do you have wedDAV module installed? I think that sometimes can create some problems with these kind of operations

Comment: @acostela, Yes, there is an icon "WebDav Authoring Rules".

Comment: Well it sounds like it may well be the webapp that is prohibiting the request then... unfortunately, you haven't told us *anything* about that, so it's hard to know which piece of code you're expecting to handle it. Please edit your question to give a lot more context.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove WebDAV from modules and handlers in

```
System.webserver

<system.webServer>
<modules>
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
</modules>
<handlers>
    <remove name="WebDAV" />
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

if this is not enough you can see this link from microsoft http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/troubleshooting-http-405-errors-after-publishing-web-api-applications